# C++ can't create, read or write a file

Tags: c++

```
std::string uncomment(std::ifstream& infile)
{
    std::fstream outfile;

    std::string buffer;
    std::string tmp;

    while(getline(infile, buffer)) {
        if(!(buffer[0] == '#')) {
            buffer += tmp;
        }
    }
    return buffer;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::string filename = argv[1];
    std::ifstream infile(filename);
    std::fstream outfile("outfile.txt");
    std::string buffer = uncomment(infile);
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl; 
    outfile << buffer << std::endl;
    outfile.close();
    infile.close();
}
```

Why this code does not produce a new file "outfile.txt"?

Why this code does not print uncommented string on line 22?

Comment: Why no error checking?  If you had included that, you would have found the answer straightaway.

Comment: In your `uncomment` method you seem to have `buffer` and `tmp` mixed up. You read into buffer and add `tmp` to it.

Comment: Those are actually two questions. Please try to ask only one! Also, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @PaulSanders I actually have error checking in the code. I just ommited it in the post to not clutter.

Comment: @Philipp, ah, how could I miss that, thank you, it all works now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what `std::fstream` does but I think you want to use `std::ofstream` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looking quickly at docs your `outfile` constructor is using the default `fstream` constructor and you don't specify the mode (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/fstream/)

Have you tried using an `ofstream` constructor since this is an output file?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to use `std::ofstream` object to create output file. Or you need to use something like this

```
std::fstream fs;
fs.open ("outfile.txt", std::fstream::out);
```

Answer (score 0):

To create file (if not exist) with `fstream` you need to pass `std::ios::out` as open mode to your `fstream` constructor. like this

```
 std::fstream outfile("outfile.txt", std::ios::out);
```

**Note :** Here you don't specified the path to your desired `outfile.txt`, so it will be generate in your project directory, make sure you check there.

Comment: Thank you. From what i understood from documentation fstream will create file if it does not exisit without need to pass additional arguments.